# With mod_disk_cache enabled how do I deny access

Tags: apache, caching

I'm having a headache with this.
I have an apache serving cached content and I want to prevent some user agents to access my content.

I've tried something like this:

`SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Wget" bad_ua
<LocationMatch "^/files/">
    Deny from env=bad_ua
</LocationMatch>`

It works fine when file isn't cached. But if the file is cached it don't seem to have any effect.
Would apreciate any help, thanks.